# Susy Media-Layouts - How is the min-width calculated?

Tags: susy-compass

In the [documentation for Media-Layouts](http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/#ref-media-layouts), you have the choice of specifying either the `min-width` argument, or the `layout` argument, or both:

```
// $media-layout: <min-width> <layout> <max-width> <ie-fallback>;
// - You must supply either <min-width> or <layout>.
$media-layout: 12;          // Use 12-col layout at matching min-width.
```

When the `min-width` argument is omitted (as above), how is this calculated? Is the `min-width` a set percentage of the specified `$column-width`?

I am currently using the `min-width`-only approach, because it seems like the cleanest way to use Susy, but I'm not actually sure how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from [the source](https://github.com/ericam/susy/blob/master/sass/susy/_media.scss) on github:

```
// Neither $min nor $max:
// We can create a breakpoint based on the number of columns in the layout.
$min: fix-ems(container-outer-width($width: false));
```

When only a layout is passed, Susy is creating min-width breakpoint to match the width of the container. When no layout is passed, there's a call to `get-layout()`, which [finds the first layout larger](https://github.com/ericam/susy/blob/master/sass/susy/_functions.scss#L338) than your given `$min` value.